# Python Pandas Extract text between words and symbols with regex

Tags: python, pandas, regex, text, regexp-replace

I am trying to extract certain words between some text and symbol using regex in Python Pandas. The problem is that sometimes there are non-characters after the word I want to extract, and sometimes there is nothing.

Here is the input table.

[image]

Here is the expected output.

[image]

I've tried this str.extract(r'[a-zA-Z\W]+\s+Reason to buy:([a-zA-Z\s]+)[a-zA-Z\W]+\s+') but does not work.

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lookaround to extract your reason to buy:

```
(?<=Reason to buy: )([^<]+)
```

And use it in your Python code as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, 'Team: Asian<>Reason to buy: leisure'             ],
    [2, 'Team: SouthAmerica<>Reason to buy: educational<>'],
    [3, 'Team: Australia<>Reason to buy: commercial'      ],
    [4, 'Team: North America<>Reason to buy: leisure<>'   ],
    [5, 'Team: Europe<>Reason to buy: leisure<>'          ],
], columns = ['team_id', 'reasons'])

pattern = r'(?<=Reason to buy: )([A-Za-z]+)'

df['reasons'] = df['reasons'].str.extract(pattern)
```

Output:

```
   team_id      reasons
0        1      leisure
1        2  educational
2        3   commercial
3        4      leisure
4        5      leisure
```

Check the Regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lOSuFa/1) and the Python [demo](https://www.online-python.com/1IOmhA7RZG).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. What does ?<= do here exactly?

Comment: Checks if before the match there's the words `Reason to buy: `, but doesn't include it in the final match. That's why it is called lookaround (specifically, lookbehind).

Comment: so it checks for any words,digits and symbols?

Comment: You need to change `([A-Za-z]+)` to change what the regex matches. If you want to match anything other than `<`, you can use `(?<=Reason to buy: )([^<]+)`.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to capture the part matching any zero or more chars up to `<>` or end of string:

```py
df['reasons'] = df['reasons'].str.extract(r"Reason to buy:\s*(.*?)(?=<>|$)", expand=False)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AGVDGY/1).

*Details*:

- `Reason to buy:` - a string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespace
- `(.*?)` - a capturing group with ID 1 that matches zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?=<>|$)` -  a positive lookahead that requires a `<>` string or end of string immediately to the right of the current location.

Note that [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) requires at least one capturing group in the pattern to actually return a value, so you can even use a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3512471/3832970) instead of the positive lookahead:

```py
df['reasons'] = df['reasons'].str.extract(r"Reason to buy:\s*(.*?)(?:<>|$)", expand=False)
```

Comment: For the capturing group (.*?), do we need the '?' ? I try to capture any text/digits/symbols from the capturing group. Thanks.

Comment: @user13617491 Yes, `.*?` "*matches zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible*"